# Execute an async method when app is terminating in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

Is it possible to run an async method when the app is terminating?

I tried using *AppLifecycle* and run my method when it's in `AppLifecycleState.detached` state but the app seems to get terminated before it can success execute my async method. The only state where it manage to fully execute my async method is when the state is in `AppLifecycleState.inactive`. Executing the async method when `AppLifecycleState.inactive` is not sufficient enough for me as the apps easily enters the inactive state (eg. when I pull down my notification shade).

Is there a way for me to achieve this? To detect if user is closing / killed the app and if yes, execute an async method before closing.

Comment: i also facing the same issue now

Comment: Could you tell us the scenario why you want this?

Comment: @AbuSayed I wanted to start a foreground service when the app is terminating